# Create method that prints the numbers between two specified numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, methods

So I'm creating a method in that is supposed to print the numbers between two specified numbers. I had it setup before in the main method but i can figure out how to make a method and call it into the main method. What my program does right now is it only prints what "int between" is equal to. I don't want anyone to just type the code out for me, i'm just looking for tips on what i should change. Last time i asked a question someone proceeded to just answer with code and it did not help me to learn anything.

So my question is what is causing the program to only display what between is equal to? I know that I need a value for the if loop to return something, but it needs to return the numbers between num1 & num2. My Professor Also said that the method needs to be "public static void Printer(int num1, int num2)" is that even possible? I kept getting an error so I switched to "int Printer".

```
package nortonaw_Assignment8;

public class Nortonaw_Assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int between;
        between = Printer(5, 20);
        System.out.println(between);
    }
public static int Printer (int num1, int num2){
    int between = 0;
    for (;num1<=num2; num1++);
    return between;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the first number is larger than the second one? e.g. `Printer(20, 5);`. Might want to consider that use case.

Comment: i was wondering the same thing as well. I was going to make it where the user entered the numbers and state that they need to enter the low number first.

Comment: To @DrewKennedy 's point: I recommend that the method throw an [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) with a message stating that the first argument should be <= the second.

Comment: Or use an if-statement to check if the first number is larger than the second. If true, simply decrement instead of incrementing.

Comment: @Drewmann have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 0):

currently your method is designed to return only one single number, so either you return a collection of numbers are you print the numbers inside `Printer`, in this case you can use the method signature suggested by your professor.

So I would write it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer(5, 20);
}
public static void Printer (int num1, int num2) {
    for (int i=num1;i<=num2; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Note that I introduced a additional counter variable `i` because I think `num1` and `num2` should not be changed as they define the boundary of your range.

Comment: thanks this works correctly, but would you be able to explain to me why you added the "int i"?

Comment: @Drewmann  I introduced a additional counter variable i because I think num1 and num2 should not be changed as they define the boundary of your range

Answer (score 0):

1) There's a difference between printing out a value and returning a value.
When you"print" a value in a function, you are just writing out the value to screen or some other medium , but when  you use the return statement, you are passing what you are returning to the caller of your function as well as control.

** I hope that makes sense to you?

2)"public static void Printer(int num1, int num2)" is possible.

Comment: hmm i'm still confused. I understand printing out a value, but do not understand the difference from returning a value. could you maybe elaborate a bit more? thanks

Comment: @Drewmann When a function which we would call sayName() is called, control of the program is transferred to the function sayName(). Control of the program would remain with sayName() until it finishes executing or it hits a return statement. So all print does, is print to screen while return transfers the result of sayName() to what triggered it as well as control of the program.

Comment: so anything in that function sayName() would then be executed because it now has control of the program? Sorry that i'm not understanding it well, i will need to do more research to properly understand how returning a value works.

Answer (score 0):

```
package printingTasks;

public class Printer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printInBetween(25, 30); //Would print 26 -> 29

    }

    /*
     * You don't need to return something if you just want to print it out to the console.
     * So you can use void as return type
     */
    public static void printInBetween(final int leftBoundary, final int rightBoundary){
        /**
         * Calculate the first number which should be printed.
         * This number would be the leftBoundery plus one
         * This number will be the starting point of your loop
         */
        final int firstNumber = leftBoundary + 1;
//      final int firstNumber = leftBoundary; //if you want to include the left boundary
        for (
                int currentNumber = firstNumber; //Set the counter of the the loop (currentNumber) to the first valid number
                currentNumber < rightBoundary;   //Run the loop while the loop counter is less than the rightBoundary
//              currentNumber <= rightBoundary;  //If you want to include the right boundary                    
                currentNumber++                  //Increment the loop counter with each iteration
                ){
            /**
             * In each iteration you will print the current value of the counter to the console
             * Because your counter (currentNumber) will be incremented from the first valid number
             * to the last number before the right boundary you will get all numbers between the two
             * boundaries. 
             */
            System.out.println(currentNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your teacher wants you to print from the Printer method not directly in the main method. All the main method should be doing is calling the Printer method.
Here is the full snippit:

```
package nortonaw_Assignment8;
public class Nortonaw_Assignment8 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Printer(5, 20);
 }
 public static void Printer (int num1, int num2) {
     for (int i = num1+1;i<=num2-1; i++) {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code, it works now. Note: num2 must always be greater than num1 in the initial Printer call. Or else you will witness an infinite loop. To fix this you can add an If statement in the Printer method: if (num2>num1) {}. @Drewmann